# How to replace HTML escape characters in JSON String in Android

Tags: java, android, html, regex, html-escape-characters

I am currently developing an android app with server synchronization. I have a php script sending me database information from a server encoded with JSON. Furthermore the german ä, ö, ü, ß and other characters are html escaped with &auml, &ouml, &uuml etc. When receiving the data in my android app I want to decode the escape characters (of course).

I googled about how to replace html escape characters in Android and found `HTML.fromHTML(htmlString).toString()` and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(htmlString)` from the `org.apache.commons.lang` library. However both just did not change the String at all.

An example of the Strings the app is receiving: `{"categories":[[0,"Rollen f&uumlr vergrabene Karte"]],"roles":[],"sets":[],"set_roles":[],"teams":[]}`

I also tried only to decode inner parts but it did not work either. That would then look like this: `[[0,"Rollen f&uumlr vergrabene Karte"]]`

How can I decode those characters without having to replaceAll every single one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml` is supposed to do the job.

However, looking at the json you're showing, apparently the server is  wrongly encoding the HTML escapes. The semicolon is not being appended,  `&uumlr` should be `&uumlr;`

I've checked using the escape `&uacute;` and `&uuml;` and it's working.

```
String json = "{\"categories\":[[0,\"Rollen f&uacute;oobar t&uuml;oo vergrabene Karte\"]],\"roles\":[],\"sets\":[],\"set_roles\":[],\"teams\":[]}";

System.out.println("=======>" + Html.fromHtml(json).toString());
```

Comment: Oh now that you mention it, where did the semicolon go... I inserted it into the database for sure. Well i will figure out on my own. Thanks :)

Comment: No problems, sometimes when we're debugging, we forget to look at these simple details.
Good luck! :D